# Custom timeline with CSS with section last child

Tags: html, css

I'm not an expert in CSS 3 yet however I attempted to hack a code I found to create a cool timeline. I need to add a code to end the timeline (step 5 in this example) without the last line going down. Any help would be appreciated. See code:

```css
section#timeline {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

/* the LINE */
section#timeline:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

/* each section */
section#timeline article {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* section clear divs */
section#timeline article:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* dots */
section#timeline article div.inner span.step {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 7px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 2em;
}


/* right column */
section#timeline article div.inner {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

/* left column  */
section#timeline article:nth-child(2n+2) div.inner {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="timeline">
  <article>
    <div class="inner">
      <span class="step">1</span>
      <div style="text-align: right;">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis rutrum nunc, eget dictum massa. Nam faucibus felis nec augue adipiscing, eget commodo libero mattis.  Mauris id finibus ligula. Aenean orci diam, ornare ac nisi et, semper fermentum risus. Phasellus vestibulum nibh orci, non auctor justo tempus et. Vestibulum pretium nulla quis ligula sollicitudin, euismod consequat enim elementum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="inner">
      <span class="step">2</span>
      <h3>Title 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis rutrum nunc, eget dictum massa. Nam faucibus felis nec augue adipiscing, eget commodo libero mattis.  Mauris id finibus ligula. Aenean orci diam, ornare ac nisi et, semper fermentum risus. Phasellus vestibulum nibh orci, non auctor justo tempus et. Vestibulum pretium nulla quis ligula sollicitudin, euismod consequat enim elementum.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="inner">
      <div style="text-align: right;">
      <span class="step">3</span>
      <h3>Title 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis rutrum nunc, eget dictum massa. Nam faucibus felis nec augue adipiscing, eget commodo libero mattis.  Mauris id finibus ligula. Aenean orci diam, ornare ac nisi et, semper fermentum risus. Phasellus vestibulum nibh orci, non auctor justo tempus et. Vestibulum pretium nulla quis ligula sollicitudin, euismod consequat enim elementum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="inner">
      <span class="step">4</span>
      <h3>Title 4</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis rutrum nunc, eget dictum massa. Nam faucibus felis nec augue adipiscing, eget commodo libero mattis.  Mauris id finibus ligula. Aenean orci diam, ornare ac nisi et, semper fermentum risus. Phasellus vestibulum nibh orci, non auctor justo tempus et. Vestibulum pretium nulla quis ligula sollicitudin, euismod consequat enim elementum.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="inner">
      <div style="text-align: right;">
      <span class="step">5</span>
      <h3>Title 5</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis rutrum nunc, eget dictum massa. Nam faucibus felis nec augue adipiscing, eget commodo libero mattis.  Mauris id finibus ligula. Aenean orci diam, ornare ac nisi et, semper fermentum risus. Phasellus vestibulum nibh orci, non auctor justo tempus et. Vestibulum pretium nulla quis ligula sollicitudin, euismod consequat enim elementum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: So, you want [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wwNrH.png) line to disappear?

Comment: Also, there’s no CSS3 in this question apart from the `border-radius` rule which isn’t really relevant.

Comment: @Xufox Yes that's correct. Sorry I didn't know about it not being css3 mostly as most of these are still new to me (I need to learn my css better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, add background to the last article (step 5).

```
section#timeline article:last-child {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

```
section#timeline {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

/* the LINE */
section#timeline:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 82%;
  background: #000;
}

/* each section */
section#timeline article {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* section clear divs */
section#timeline article:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* dots */
section#timeline article div.inner span.step {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 7px solid #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 2em;
}


/* right column */
section#timeline article div.inner {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

/* left column  */
section#timeline article:nth-child(2n+2) div.inner {
  float: right;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/z3pphndj/)

Comment: section#timeline:before  change height:100% to height:82% @mugé

Comment: Oh.. I see.  So the line goes all the way down and you kept it shorter.  Nice!

Comment: Thanks @ivinraj I wasn't able to vote up (no priveleges) until today :) so I did vote up. Although both answers worked, the other worked better for my theme. Thanks for your input anyway, duly appreciated! :)

Comment: Okay Sir My pleasure@sdesign